# Why do I get a warning saying "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"?

Tags: c, sockets, gcc-warning

This is my code for receiving the raw packets from Ethernet in promiscuous mode.  while compiling I get a warning in the line of code

```
logfile=open("sniff_data.bin",O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_TRUNC,0777);
```

Warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]. I checked in google but couldn't find the solution.
Can anybody tell me the solution and where have I gone wrong?

```
void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* , int);
void print_ip_header(unsigned char* , int);
void print_tcp_packet(unsigned char * , int );
void print_udp_packet(unsigned char * , int );
void print_icmp_packet(unsigned char* , int );
void PrintData (unsigned char* , int);

FILE *logfile;
struct sockaddr_in source,dest;
int i,j;

int main()
{
    int saddr_size,data_size;
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    gopromiscous();
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(1024);  

    logfile=open("sniff_data.bin",O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_TRUNC,0777);  

    if(logfile==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to create sniff_data file.");
    }
    printf("\n Starting..\n");

    int sock_raw = socket( AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL)) ;
    setsockopt(sock_raw , SOL_SOCKET , SO_BINDTODEVICE , "eth0" , strlen("eth0")+ 1 );

    if(sock_raw < 0)
    {

        perror("Socket Error");
        return 1;
    }
    int count=30; 
    while(count>=0)
    { 
        count--;
        saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
        //Receive a packet
        data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 1024, 0 , &saddr , 
          (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
        if(data_size <0 )
        {
            printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
            return 1;
        }

        fwrite(buffer, data_size, 1, logfile);    

    }

    fclose(logfile);
    close(sock_raw);
    printf("\n");
    printf(" Finished\n\n");
    return 0;
}


int gopromiscous()
  {

    int fd;
    struct ifreq eth;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(0x800));

    strcpy(eth.ifr_name, "eth0");

    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &eth);

    eth.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;

    ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &eth);

    printf("\n Entered Promiscuous Mode Successfully\n");

 }
```

Comment: Why not read the manual page?

Comment: because i am writing the data to socket .mean to say i am including this as a function in other program.

Comment: The `open` function - http://linux.die.net/man/2/open - Then you know the return type

Comment: can i use this ? logfile=fopen("sniff_data.bin","wb"); will it trunc all the data when re executing?

Comment: If you read the manual page you will note that `open` returns an integer not a `FILE *`. Why not read http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen and indeed this flag will truncate

Answer (score 6):

from man 2 open

```
    int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

Open return an int (file descriptor), not a FILE *.
Thus the warning, and reason why your code won't work.

You might want to change FILE * to int, and use write(2) and close(2) instead of fwrite and flcose

Or use fopen(3)

Comment: i am using fwrite because its a binary file!

Comment: @user2963407 open(2) does work with binary files also. You just have to be careful retaining the size of the file, and not looking for a '\0'. The size is returned by read(2)

Comment: @user2963407 you can also use fopen(3) if you want to work with FILE *

Comment: Being a binary file doesn't compel you to use `fwrite()`.

Answer (score 2):

or use fopen() to return a FILE *

Comment: but when i use fopen, i get warning : passing argument 2 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: @user2963407 Show us how you are using it. I would simply use `fopen("sniff_data.bin",a+)` in case you want to append to the end of the file.

Comment: the parameters to fopen() are different than for open().  But switching of fopen() changes less of your other code.

Answer (score 0):

`open()` function call returns `file descriptor` which is  `int` type. but you are assigning open return value to `file stream` which is `FILE *` type.

when you use `open()` you should use `close()` with the specific descriptor not `fclose()`

Comment: yes you are write, but i have used fwrite to write the data, because its a binary file.

Comment: then use `fopen()` to open file instead of `open()` and return file strem (FILE *).

Comment: but when i use fopen, i get warning : passing argument 2 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: or can i use this logfile=fopen("sniff_data.bin","wb");

Comment: You can use and when you use `"w" or "wb"`  mode file truncates everything if file exists.